# How to write markdown for arrow with two directions and words above and below?

Tags: markdown

I want to use Markdown to show the following picture:

[image]

I have read

[Arrows with different directions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450078/arrows-with-different-directions)

But it's about LaTeX and it did not work under Markdown.

How to use Markdown to write the above picture?

Comment: Which Markdown processor are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markdown itself doesn't do anything like this. [Its scope is quite limited](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> The idea for Markdown is to make it easy to read, write, and edit prose. HTML is a *publishing* format; Markdown is a *writing* format. Thus, Markdown’s formatting syntax only addresses issues that can be conveyed in plain text.

It's true that extensions and flavours of Markdown have subsequently been released that add features to the original format, e.g. tables and strikethrough.

But to show something like you want you'll need to use something like [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) or [MathML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML). It simply isn't supported by Markdown or HTML natively. All Markdown extensions that I've seen supporting this kind of notation rely on some LaTeX implementation to do the rendering.

Depending on the Markdown implementation you're using you might already be able to use LaTeX. For example, [Jupyter enables LaTeX via MathJax using `$` and `$$` delimiters](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Working%20With%20Markdown%20Cells.html#LaTeX-equations). If your implementation doesn't support LaTeX out of the box you may be able to add it, e.g. using the aforementioned [MathJax JavaScript library](https://www.mathjax.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this in [Doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html).

```
# Markdown for arrow with 2 directions & labels above & below

## Intro

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 

## Important diagram

Uses Graphviz Dot to create the diagram.

\dot
digraph G {
  rankdir="LR";
  node[shape=none, fontsize=56]

  1 -> 2 [label="a"]
  2 -> 1 [label="b"]

  3 -> 4 [label="d"]
  4 -> 3 [label="e"]
}
\enddot

## Summary

Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis
natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur.
```

#### Resulting HTML

The generated HTML will display similar to this:

---

[image: Web page fragment generated from markdown]

---

### Label position

By default the labels are above the lines. To move the labels add an`lp` attribute to the edge.

```
2 -> 1 [label="b", lp=12]
```

Where `lp` means **l**abel **p**osition and `12` is the centre position of the label

Attributes are described in the Graphviz [Node, Edge and Graph Attributes](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html) page.